# Pandas json_normalize with timestamps as keys

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read this JSON data

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "1510122047": [
                35.7,
                256
            ]
        },
        {
            "1510125000": [
                41.7,
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "1510129000": [
                31.7,
                0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and normalize it into a pandas data frame of this format:

[image: data frame]

I tried it with `json_normalize` but I was not able to get the result I need.
Here is what I tried: But it's not quite efficient. I would like to find a solution that works with pandas' built in functions to do this. I'd appreciate ideas!

```python
import pandas
import json

s = """
{"values": [
            {
              "1510122047": [35.7, 256]
            },
            {
              "1510125000": [41.7, 7]
            },
            {
              "1510129000": [31.7, 0]
            }
          ]}
"""

data = json.loads(s)

normalized_data = []
for value in data['values']:
    timestamp = list(value.keys())[0]
    normalized_data.append({'timestamp':timestamp, 'value_1': value[timestamp][0], 'value_2': value[timestamp][1]})

pandas.DataFrame(normalized_data)
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately none where faster than the solution of this OP. Here is what I did to generate a bigger payload and test for speed:
I guess it's the nature of JSON to be slowly for this application.

```python
import pandas
import json
import time

s1 = """{
              "1510122047": [35.7, 256]
            },
            {
              "1510125000": [41.7, 7]
            },
            {
              "1510129000": [31.7, 0]
            }"""

s = """
{"values": [
            {
              "1510122047": [35.7, 256]
            },
            {
              "1510125000": [41.7, 7]
            },
            {
              "1510129000": [31.7, 0]
            },
""" + ",".join([s1]*1000000) + "]}"

data = json.loads(s)

tic = time.time()

normalized_data = []
for value in data['values']:
    timestamp = list(value.keys())[0]
    normalized_data.append({'timestamp':timestamp, 'value_1': value[timestamp][0], 'value_2': value[timestamp][1]})

print(time.time() - tic)
pandas.DataFrame(normalized_data)
```

Comment: How is the json stored? Is it in a file, variable or an object?

Comment: how does that matter to my question?

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using a nested comprehension

**Ex:**

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[key] + value for item in data['values'] 
                            for key, value in item.items()
                 ], columns=["Timestamp", "Val_1", "Val_2"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Timestamp  Val_1  Val_2
0  1510122047   35.7    256
1  1510125000   41.7      7
2  1510129000   31.7      0
```

Comment: This is nice and readable but not more efficient than the solution of the original post. I tested it with a bigger payload and it takes twice as much as time as the original post's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'values': [{'1510122047': [35.7, 256]},
  {'1510125000': [41.7, 7]},
  {'1510129000': [31.7, 0]}]}

dfn = json_normalize(data, 'values').stack()
df_output = pd.DataFrame(dfn.tolist(), index=dfn.index)
df_output = df_output.reset_index().iloc[:, 1:]



# rename columns
df_output.columns = 'value_' + df_output.columns.astype(str)
df_output.rename(columns={'value_level_1':'timestamp'}, inplace=True)
print(df_output)

#     timestamp  value_0  value_1
# 0  1510122047     35.7      256
# 1  1510125000     41.7        7
# 2  1510129000     31.7        0
```

Comment: I tested it with a bigger payload and it takes ten times as much as time as the original post's solution.